# Dynamically creating nested for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I suspect I'm missing something super basic and just looking at this problem wrong so I would be happy if anyone could point me in the right direction.  Here's my problem:

I have a list of variables and, for simplicity, they always contain the value. I want to have my code go through all the possible options. Here's the way I quickly thought to do it:

```
num_apples = 100
num_pears = 100

for current_apple in range(0,num_apples+1):
    for current_pear in range(0, num_pears+1):
        print current_apple, " - ", current_pear
```

The good thing about this code is I can break out of loops easily(i.e. say I don't want current_apple + current_pear > 50 or something), but the major drawback is I need to know specifically how many variables(fruits in this case) that I'm starting with and often I won't know.

Is there a way to dynamically create the for loop type structure above so I can control when to break a sub loop but without knowing specifically how many variables I'll have ahead of time?

EDIT: Ideally I think it would be easier for me, if I could increase the size of one variable at a time so I can break out of the loop once the variable get out of range that is useful to me.

Comment: Can't you use recursion?

Comment: Recursion is the answer

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo sorry its been a while, I'll look into recursions. Thanks!

Comment: `while` may be an even easier option, if you can define what condition should exit the loop.

Comment: You have to know ahead of time what value is "out of range" so you have to have a way to calculate that - even to generate a dynamic portion of code to break there. Given that you can calculate your end goal from your inputs - why can't you just use a standard break in the loops in your example. Or make a base case for a recursive function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`itertools.product` is equivalent to nested for loops.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
>>> import itertools
>>> counts = [1, 2, 3]
>>> ranges = [range(x) for x in counts]
>>> for i in itertools.product(*ranges):
...     print i
... 
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
>>>
```

Comment: I was thinking of an itertools solution, too, but this doesn't work if you don't know the counts beforehand...which I think is the OP's problem, although it's not very clear.

Comment: @TimPietzcker You can break out of the loop or stop retrieving elements from the generator if you don't need anymore.

Comment: I tried to run it but I'm unsure how to stop a item from growing.  For example, say I have 10 items and each item has a range of 10.  If the forth item hits 4, how do I stop that item from growing but letting it continue to grow the other numbers?

Comment: @Lostsoul Break out of the loop?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: How does that allow the other variables to grow?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I don't understand how to do that in this case.  Say I have a output like this: 
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 9, 9, 9, 9)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
How can I find that number "4" and say I do not want that item to grow more than 4 while growing the other numbers?

Comment: @Lostsoul: `if i[4] > 3: continue`

Comment: The `product` function will continue iteration through all combinations but you can simply ignore those combinations that you are not interested in using `continue`.

Comment: @FogleBird cool thanks. Is it possible to have it not iterate the ranges I do not want? or how can I do that?  The reason being the ranges I have are very large(50-100 variables with a range of about 1000 each) but once a threshold is reached I won't need any results above that. Is that possible?